# $S^1$ action on vector space implies $\mathbb{Z}$-grading?

Tags: functional-analysis, group-actions

Suppose I have an action of $S^1$ on $V$, where $V$ is a complex vector space. This means I have a homomorphism
$$
S^1\to\operatorname{GL}(V,\mathbb{C})\\
\lambda\mapsto D_\lambda,
$$
where
$$
D_{\lambda\mu}=D_\lambda D_\mu.
$$
Does this entail that I get a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on $V$? If so, how?
I think that if we show that $D_\lambda$ is diagonalizable for each $\lambda$ then we are done since these operators commute.

Comment: Why do you expect a $\mathbb Z$-grading? Me, I'm thinking $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ and $\lambda \mapsto R_\lambda$ where $R_\lambda$ is rotation by the angle $\lambda$.

Comment: Because this is what happens on symmetric polynomials. But maybe that is because they also have a ring/algebra structure?

Comment: With symmetric polynomials, you start with a graded algebra: $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and then every graded piece is $S_n$-invariant. So for example, I can take the vector space $V_d$ of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$. Then $V_d$ is not graded but it is an $S_n$-module.

Comment: Also keep in mind the difference between $S_n$-invariant and $S_n$-module. The set of symmetric polynomials is $S_n$-invariant and therefore forms a very boring $S_n$-module. The set of all polynomials has a more interesting $S_n$-module structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes if $V$ is equipped with an inner product making it a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) and the action of $S^1$ is continuous. Then we can average the inner product over the $S^1$-action to get an invariant inner product making this a unitary representation, which is then completely reducible by the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem#Decomposition_of_a_unitary_representation). $V$ is then graded by isotypic components: for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ the $n^{th}$ graded component $V_n$ is the subspace of $V$ on which $z \in S^1$ acts by $z^n$.

The most famous special case of this is the regular representation on $L^2(S^1)$, where the decomposition above recovers the theory of Fourier series.

This takes care of the case that $V$ is finite-dimensional, since finite-dimensional inner product spaces are always Hilbert spaces. It's less clear to me what happens in general. If we really want to work with bare vector spaces without an inner product or anything like that, then we can replace actions of $S^1$ with actions of the multiplicative [group scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_scheme) $\mathbb{G}_m$, which correspond to $\mathbb{Z}$-gradings for vector spaces over any field.

Comment: You might object that without a multiplicative structure it's unclear in what sense these deserve to be called $\mathbb{Z}$-gradings, as opposed to just direct sum decompositions. But they do, and that's because of the way they interact with tensor product of representations.

Comment: I mean, if you're being _completely_ general and just literally considering arbitrary representations of $S^1$ as just a group, then $S^1$ is just a product of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and a big $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, so its group algebra certainly is not semisimple and there are modules that don't have any nice grading.